# Como quitar el nombre del proyecto que sale en la notificacion en c#

Tags: c#

[image: Aqui muestra ese dato de capaPresentacion quisiera quitar esa parte]

aqui es donde hago que aparezca la notificacion

```
      if (InsertarDatosCliente())
        {

            Notificacion.ShowBalloonTip(600000000);
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido completar el registro, intente nuevamente si el error persiste contacte al servicio tecnico","Aviso",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
```

y aqui es donde cargo el texto a mostrar

```
    Notificacion.BalloonTipTitle =t_NombreCliente.Text+""+t_ApellidoPaterno.Text+" "+t_ApellidoMaterno.Text;
    Notificacion.BalloonTipText = "Se ha registrado como nuevo cliente";
    //
```

alguien podria ayudarme ya intente con las propiedades y no hay como quitar eso de la capa presentacion

Comment: que libreria de `Notificacion` utilizas ? es algo que has creado o una libreria de terceros

Comment: Es el Notyficon el componente de windowsform

Answer (score 0):

La unica propiedad que no estas asignando es el `Text`, valida que contenido tiene esta en las propiedades

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quizas debas simplementes dejalo en blanco

Comment: esta en blanco aun asi sigue saliendo capaPresentacion

Comment: y si ingresas algun texto en esa propiedad ?

Comment: sii ya intente con eso tambien y aun asi sigue saliendome CapaPresentacion

Comment: ya solucione intente agregar otro nuevo componente y no active la propiedad BalldoTipIcon solo deje en estado "none" y dejo de salirme la CapaPresentacion en la notificacion